# Firefox-library time display not syncing right

Tags: 16.04, firefox, time

Time showing next to downloaded file show 2:16 AM (Arabic-٢:١٦ ص) which is inaccurate. System time top-right and downloaded file properties has correct time.

The current screen-shot shows system time is: 07:21:48 EET. You can see that the file properties window of a just downloaded mp4 which seems to be in-sync with system time shown at top right 19:22 EET. While Firefox download library window shows time at 2:16 AM.

I am using the Firefox-supported extension 'download youtube videos as mp4 1.8.10' to download this file.

This post is to figure out why time is not syncing right. And if error-check of Firefox should have noticed this difference.

Firefox v. 53.0.3 (32-bit)

```
$ uname -a
Linux alaa-HP-Pavilion-dv2700-Notebook-PC 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP 
Thu Apr 27 15:28:22 UTC 2017 i686 athlon i686 
GNU/Linux

$ date -R
Sun, 04 Jun 2017 19:22:51 +0200
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: To the right of  'googlevideo .com' you see '٢:٣١ ص'  which is 2:31AM in English.

Comment: Alright. You need to clarify things like that! Not everybody can read Persian and this is an English-only web site after all. Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: For reference, could you please include the output of the *terminal* command `date -R` and the *Javascript* command `Date()` (open Firefox, press Ctrl+Shift+K to open the developer console, select the *Console* tab and enter the command in the prompt at the bottom)? Thanks.

Comment: No luck  with the developer console.

Comment: Oh, the shortcut for the developer console is actually Ctrl+Shift+I. You can also open it through the Firefox menu (in the top right corner).

Answer (score 1):

After reading up on this a bit, it would seem that Mozilla applications use your system time zone. You can check which one Firefox thinks you're using by opening the developer console (F12) and typing

```
Date()
```

which would give you something that looks like this:

```
"Sun May 21 2017 18:51:58 GMT-0400 (EDT)".
```

If nothing else it would perhaps clear up a few things.

I would also double check your Date and Time preferences in MATE.

Comment: Date at terminal: ر ماي 31 02:48:27 EET 2017, that seems correct. Could not locate the Firefox console where your Date () maybe entered.

Comment: It looks fine now F12 Date() and download time are in sync with MATE time.  Whether it was fixed by Firefox upgrade to 55.0.2 (32-bit) or network changes--  not clear.